# Is it safe to synchronize java.awt.Container.paint(Graphics g)?

Tags: java, synchronization, awt

I'm using some 3rd party AWT components in a desktop application.  The component's layout is changed within the `paint()` method, and this causes some very strange behaviour.  This appears to be fixed by adding the `synchronized` keyword to the paint() method, but is this a safe thing to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `paint()` method is called outside the [event dispatch thread](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html), which can indeed cause very strange behaviour, which is why it should never be done.

Instead of `paint()`, application code should only ever call [`repaint()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint())

Comment: Thanks Michael.  `paint(Graphics)` was being called from `update(Graphics)`.  I changed `update()` so it now calls `repaint()` and it seems to work so far...

Comment: @Michael any idea if it's safe to call `repaint()` from `update(Graphics)`?

Comment: @Alison: calling repaint() is safe, as it basically just drops an event into the EDT queue, which is synchronized properly.

Comment: @Alison: But there's a different problem: calling paint() from update() should actually be OK, since update() itself should only run on the EDT. Is your code calling update() directly? You may want to read http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html to make sure you understand how Swing/AWT components are supposed to work.

Comment: @Michael From reading that link, it sounds like update shouldn't be overridden at all, and it certainly shouldn't be calling `repaint()` as that will just trigger another `update()`.

Comment: @Alison: According to the API doc of update(), it is intended to be overridden. But yes, it should not call repaint().

Answer (score 1):

The paint method should only be called within one thread, the Event Dispatch Thread,  so there is no need to synchronize.  I would imagine that the root of the problem lies in how the components are being used.  Take a look at [this link](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for some ideas around concurrency in the UI.

Comment: Interesting.  In my case, synchronizing definitely fixes issues, so clearly it's being called from more than one thread.  I'll investigate where that might be occurring.

Comment: Other methods that are permitted to run in different threads could theoretically hold the same lock.

Comment: @Tom very good point, and it explains why synchronizing paint() fixed the issue - things were happening in another synchronized thread which changed the layout mid-paint.